# Multiple Service Workers for Django application

Tags: javascript, python, django, amazon-s3, service-worker

At Django website I have several applications. For each application I need separate ServiceWorker. Let's say, when user goes to

https://mysite/app/1 sw1.js is loaded, when to

https://mysite/app/2 sw2.js and so on.

All the service workers files  are located at Amazon S3 bucket.

I can register service worker on the index page of each application in a normal way. However, the scope of the service worker is defined based on sw.js location which is S3 bucket path.

To change the scope I have to either place the sw.js [to the root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780397/understanding-service-worker-scope) of each application what is impossible or to return extended http header 'Service-Worker-Allowed' what is [restricted by S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916929/custom-headers-on-amazon-s3)

One of the solution is probably to use [CloudFront/S3 with Lambda@Edge](https://medium.com/@tom.cook/edge-lambda-cloudfront-custom-headers-3d134a2c18a2) to return correct header but it looks too complex.

Is there any simpler solutions to define the correct scope of sw?